# Extract XML using lxml/etree from instructions in dict

Tags: python, pandas, xml, lxml

I would like to extract data from an xml file and add it to a DataFrame. Since the xml file is layered, I cannot use the convenient [`pandas.read_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) function without providing an XSLT script to flatten the file. Since I believe this would reduce the legibility of the code, I am currently using the [`objectify()` function of the lxml package](https://lxml.de/objectify.html) like so:

```xml
<validElementaryExchanges majorRelease="3" minorRelease="0" majorRevision="0" minorRevision="44038" xmlns="http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02">
  <elementaryExchange id="38a622c6-f086-4763-a952-7c6b3b1c42ba" unitId="487df68b-4994-4027-8fdc-a4dc298257b7" formula="C4H10O2" casNumber="000110-63-4">
    <name xml:lang="en">1,4-Butanediol</name>
    <unitName xml:lang="en">kg</unitName>
    <compartment subcompartmentId="e8d7772c-55ca-4dd7-b605-fee5ae764578">
      <compartment xml:lang="en">air</compartment>
      <subcompartment xml:lang="en">urban air close to ground</subcompartment>
    </compartment>
    <synonym xml:lang="en">butane-1,4-diol</synonym>
    <synonym xml:lang="en">Butylene glycol</synonym>
    <property propertyId="6393c14b-db78-445d-a47b-c0cb866a1b25" amount="0" />
    <property propertyId="6d9e1462-80e3-4f10-b3f4-71febd6f1168" amount="0" />
    <property propertyId="a9358458-9724-4f03-b622-106eda248916" amount="0" />
    <property propertyId="c74c3729-e577-4081-b572-a283d2561a75" amount="0.533098393070742" />
    <property propertyId="3a0af1d6-04c3-41c6-a3da-92c4f61e0eaa" amount="1" />
    <property propertyId="67f102e2-9cb6-4d20-aa16-bf74d8a03326" amount="1" />
  </elementaryExchange>
</validElementaryExchanges>
```

```py
def extract_metadata(node):
    return {
        'id': node.get('id'),
        'name': node.name.text,
        'comp': o.compartment.compartment.text,
        'subcomp': o.compartment.subcompartment.text
    }

root = lxml.objectify.parse(file).getroot()
df = pd.DataFrame([extract_metadata(i) for i in root.iterchildren()])
```

However, I would like to put this into a function to which I can pass the instructions on what to extract from the xml file:

```py
dict_data_extraction = {
    'id': "node.get('id')",
    'name': "node.name.text",
    'comp': "o.compartment.compartment.text",
    'subcomp': "o.compartment.subcompartment.text"

df = extract_data(file, dict_data_extraction)
}
```

What is the best way to pass the etree/lxml instructions to a function? Or is there a neat way to achieve this using the `xpath` parameter of the `pandas.read_xml()` function?

Comment: Why a dictionary with properties and values that are strings instead of a function/lambda doing e.g. `lambda node: { 'id': node.get('id', 'name', node.name.text, .. }`?

Comment: Given the XML in the post  - how should the df look like?

Comment: Is that the whole XML? Do `elementaryExchange` nodes recur? Expected DataFrame would be one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the build in package `xml.etree.ElementTree` like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("Instruction.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text)
```

Pandas is also possible, but you don't have any advantage, it works best for **property** tag, but you can extend it for other tags too and `pd.concat([df1, df2, ...])` the separat dataframes in the end:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("Instruction.xml", 'r') as f:
    xml = f.read()

df_elementaryExchange = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:elementaryExchange', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_elementaryExchange.to_string())

df_name = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:name', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_name)

df_unitName = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:unitName', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_unitName)

df_compartment_parent = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:compartment', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_compartment_parent)

df_compartment = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:compartment/xmlns:compartment', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_compartment)

df_subcompartment = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:subcompartment', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_subcompartment)

df_synonym = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:synonym', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_synonym)

df_property = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath ='.//xmlns:property', namespaces={"xmlns": "http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold02"})
print(df_property)
```

Hope I could help a little bit.

Comment: Why use `open` since `read_xml` can directly read an XML file?

Comment: [@Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait), ```runntime``` is much shorter, read once: a) with file read once: Execution time: 21.142244338989258 milliseconds; b) with read for each df:
Execution time: 83.16373825073242 milliseconds

Comment: Very interesting! As original author, I will look into this if reproducible.

Comment: Measured on python3.11.